# Abandon one ServiceBus message from a batch in Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I'm writing an Azure Function with ServiceBus trigger that receives a batch of messages.
How can I abandon a specific message in the batch?
Throwing an exception results in the whole batch being abandoned.

Update:
Found what I'm looking for here: [How to manually handle message completion in C# azure function with azure service bus 5.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68350196/how-to-manually-handle-message-completion-in-c-sharp-azure-function-with-azure-s)

Comment: What Functions SDK are you using?

Comment: @SeanFeldman I'm using Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions v3.0.13